# How do you put a bounty on someone on GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was in GTA Online freeroam and someone was following me around with a fighter jet, shooting me.  For future reference, how do I put a bounty on his head?

Comment: I *think* it's by calling Lester.

Comment: i called him but it went to his voicemail

Comment: What level are you up to?

Comment: i'm on level fifteen

Comment: I bet that was me. It ain't easy trying to kill someone with that jet!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call Lester, he will help you put a bounty on other players.

Comment: thanks.  my friend says i need to visit lester in person before i can call to set up bounties.  Also, it appears i can't see bounties on players either until i visit lester.

Answer (score 5):

Call Lester and select the bounty option. This will let you put a bounty on another player.

Note that you unlock this at level 10, and can only put bounties on other players who are at least level 10.

Comment: Somebody was nuking me from orbit. Another guy was turning me into swiss cheese with a laser cannon or something. I only got the game like a week ago. Maybe with a bounty, they can harass each other instead of me.