# Set Bounty Still Locked

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

For some reason my 'Set Bounty' option in the Lester phone call menu is still locked.

I have been to see Lester, and am level 172.

Has any one seen any thing like this before, and is there a fix? I could just be missing something obvious here, but I looks like it should be unlocked.

Comment: [The Wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133635/how-do-you-put-a-bounty-on-someone-on-gta-online) says you need to see Lester at his House.  There will be an "L" on the map marking his location.  I don't remember if you meet him prior to that but that's where you first unlock bounties.

Comment: I don't think it that, I've been to see Lester a couple of times and I don't have a blip for him

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug with the game, It's locked for me despite my high level.
Coincidentally I have a Daily Objective requiring that I kill a player with a bounty.
[image: Calling Lester to set bounty]

[image]

**EDIT:**
Rockstar replied!

> Rockstar has disabled the Daily Objective relating to bounties on PS3 and 360 – this should prevent any players from being unable to complete their Daily Objectives while bounties are not available.
>
> Again we apologize for this inconvenience.
>
> Please refer to the “Cheat method affecting PC, PS3, and Xbox 360 systems in GTA Online” KB article for more information about this.

They also directed my attention to this [article](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005592527). Which states:-

> We are aware of a new method where cheaters are manipulating the Rank and in-game funds of other players on the previous generation consoles (PS3 and Xbox 360) and PC in GTA Online.  We are actively working on a fix for this issue, and may temporarily disable some minor game features while we work on a resolution. Please check back on this article for updates.